# How to stop canvas jumping animation

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas animation which you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/72a7bqbr/).

I've noticed that once you have watched the animation after a while (approximately 25 seconds) the animation starts to jump around. I'm struggling to figure out how to make it so that it is one constant fluid motion?

Code below:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).width);
canvas.height = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).height);

var P = 4;
var A = 4;

function draw(shift) {
   var w = canvas.width;
   var h = canvas.height;
   shift = shift >= 500*Math.PI ? shift - 100*Math.PI : shift;
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
   var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, w, h);
   grd.addColorStop(0, "#4a8bf5");
   grd.addColorStop(1, "#f16b55");
   ctx.strokeStyle = grd;

   ctx.lineCap = "round";
   for (var i = 0; i < w; ) {
      var _A = Math.abs(A*Math.cos(2*i));
      ctx.beginPath();
      var pos = Math.exp(-_A * i / w) * Math.sin(P * Math.PI * (i + shift) / w);
      pos *= h / 2;
      var lw = Math.exp(-_A * i / w) * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI * (i - shift) / w) * 2;
      ctx.lineWidth = (lw)+1;
      ctx.lineTo(i, h / 2 - pos);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.stroke();
      i += 1;
   }

   window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
      draw(shift + 1);
   });
}
draw(0);
```

Comment: What you see entirely hinges on `shift = shift >= 500*Math.PI ? shift - 100*Math.PI : shift;`, meaning as soon as shift reaches `1571` after roughly 26 seconds, there's a first jump because inside your `sin()` and `cos()` you aren't using multiples of 2 Pi.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make sure that the change in shift results in the `sin()` argument changing by a multiple of 2π.

Given

```
Math.sin((i + shift) / (w / P))
```

this can be done using something like

```
if (shift > 500) shift -= 2 * Math.PI * (w / P);
```

There will still be a jump in the 2nd `sin()` argument here, the line width. To avoid this, `shift` has to be reduced by a number that causes both arguments to change by multiples of 2π, the LCM if you will.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).width);
canvas.height = parseInt(getComputedStyle(canvas).height);

var P = 10;
var A = 4;

var shift = 0;

function draw() {
  var w = canvas.width;
  var h = canvas.height;
  shift += 1;
  if (shift > 500) shift -= 2 * Math.PI * (w / P);
  shift_el.innerHTML = shift;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, w, h);
  grd.addColorStop(0, "#4a8bf5");
  grd.addColorStop(1, "#f16b55");
  ctx.strokeStyle = grd;

  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  for (var i = 0; i < w;) {
    var _A = Math.abs(A * Math.cos(2 * i));
    ctx.beginPath();
    var pos = Math.exp(-_A * i / w) * Math.sin((i + shift) / (w / P));
    pos *= h / 2;
    var lw = Math.exp(-_A * i / w) * Math.sin(3 * Math.PI * (i - shift) / w) * 2;
    ctx.lineWidth = (lw) + 1;
    ctx.lineTo(i, h / 2 - pos);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    i += 1;
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

#shift_el {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="shift_el"></div>
```